# clientRequest.logPrefix() does not match connection Id reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient log message

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I am using :

org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'

'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

The connection id  in reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer logs matches the exchange.getLogPrefix(). However for the WebClient the connection ids do not match

```
        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                        HttpClient
                                .create()
                                .wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient", LogLevel.INFO, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)
                ))
                .baseUrl(foo)
                .defaultHeader("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultHeader("Authorization", fooo)
                .filter(logRequest())
                .build();
    }

    private static ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {

            String logPrefix = clientRequest.logPrefix();
            LOGGER.info("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + logPrefix);
            return Mono.just(clientRequest);
            });

    }
```

The prefix "2b7dbaa5" from the logRequest() method above :

2023-03-10T16:10:25.545+11:00  INFO 5616 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] com.foo.api.application.AppConfig       : @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@[**2b7dbaa5**]

**Does not match** "add08934"

2023-03-10T16:10:25.866+11:00  INFO 5616 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [**add08934**] REGISTERED

2023-03-10T16:10:25.952+11:00  INFO 5616 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [**add08934**] CONNECT: fooo/

2023-03-10T16:10:26.277+11:00  INFO 5616 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [**add08934**, L:/192.168.18.244:5504 - R:fooo/] ACTIVE

2023-03-10T16:10:26.583+11:00  INFO 5616 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [**add08934**, L:/192.168.18.244:5504 - R:fooo/] READ COMPLETE

2023-03-10T16:10:26.962+11:00  INFO 5616 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient     : [**add08934**, L:/192.168.18.244:5504 - R:foo/] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)

Comment: Can you try `ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor` instead of `ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor`?

Comment: Thanks @Violeta. 
Yes, clientResponse.logPrefix() matches logs



Please advise why two ids  in clientResponse.logPrefix() vslue: [14f14890] [26abf841-1]. Only 26abf841 appears in logs 

Also 2 connection id for reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer  please advise
[ae7bb67f, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:4202] REGISTERED
[da2ea363, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:4203] REGISTERED
[ae7bb67f, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:4202] ACTIVE
[da2ea363, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:4203] ACTIVE

Thanks for your help !